# How can I replace white space in filename of uploaded file

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm making a SWF uploader and have my HTML form done.

It works totally fine until I upload a SWF file with spaces in the name.

How can I replace whitespace with underscores?

I have tried...

```
str_replace(" ","_", $file);
```

...and...

```
preg_replace(" ","_", $file);
```

Comment: You don't need to put `[PHP]` in the title of your question.

Answer (score 14):

> How can I replace whitespace with underscores?

The `\s` character class will match whitespace characters. I've added the `+` quantifier to collapse multiple whitespace to one `_`. If you don't want that, remove the `+`.

```
$file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $file);
```

Answer (score 7):

the function is correct but you have to assign it to a variable.

```
$filename = str_replace/preg_replace(" ","_", $file);
```

Comment: i know. but i copied just what you posted. i thought you would know how to handle it :)

Comment: I would, but not sure about the OP :D

Answer (score 4):

I usually approach it from the other side and only allow characters from a white-list; I replace everything except these characters:

```
$file = preg_replace("/[^-_a-z0-9]+/i", "_", $file);
```

Comment: @alex true, but I think this illustrates better what I mean.

Comment: You are right, if the OP has limited regex experience, then seeing the chars explicitly will probably assist them in grokking it.

Comment: @alex and because I'm to lazy to write an explanation like you did :)